# C#.NET How to copy date to clipboard from DateTimePicker area of another application?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, clipboard

I want to create an application to copy and increase date from another application.

I can copy string numbers and increase it very well via clipboard. But I can't copy anything in `datetimepicker`. Also CTRL+C or Copy/Paste do not work as well.

How can I copy the text to the clipboard from `DateTimePicker` in another application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following snippet in `winforms` to copy a string to the clipboard.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myVar))
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(myVar);
}
```

Comment: I use same method for any text but DateTimePİcker doesn't allow to copy the value. It can not be copied manually with keyboard (ctlr+c) or mouse click as well.

The problem is about DateTimePicker.